# "Reducing Salary" challenge

Tags: java, programming-challenge

The [problem](http://codeforces.com/group/CutsHl3RGE/contest/222732/problem/F) I am trying to solve is as follows:

> ### F. Reducing Salary
>
> time limit per test: 2 seconds
>   memory limit per test: 256 megabytes
>
> Sohieb started working at Hogwarts School of Witchcraft and Wizardry.
>   Ibrahim The school headmaster told him that he will get a positive
>   integer salary equals X, then Ibrahim made a spell that erase the
>   right most digit of X every month.
>
> For example if he gets X = 1234 in the first month, the second month
>   he will get X = 123 and in the third month X = 12, and so on.
>
> After a few months Sohieb realized that he didn't get a salary because
>   X became Zero.
>
> Sohieb now has a total money equals Y which is his salary for all the
>   previous months, but he can't remember what was the value of X. Could
>   you help him by telling him what value of X makes his total money
>   equals Y.
>
> **Input**
>
> The only line of the input contains a single integer Y (1 ≤ Y ≤ 
>   10<sup>18</sup>)
>
> **Output**
>
> Print single integer — the value of X which makes the total  money
>   equals Y.   If there is many values of X holds print "ManySolutions"
>   (without the  quotes).   If there is no X makes the total money equal
>   Y print -1.
>
> Examples:
>
> input 1 output 1 
> input 3000 output 2701 
> input 565 output -1

---

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Salary {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int left, right, sal;
    left =0;
    right = input.nextInt();
    sal = right;
    int presal = init(sal,left,right);
    System.out.println(presal);
}
public static int init(int sal, int left, int right){
    int mid = (left+right)/2;
    int count =mid;
    int sum =0;
    while (count>0){
        sum+=count;
        count/=10;
    }


     while (left>=0 && left<=right){
            if(sum<sal){
                return init(sal,mid+1,right);
            }
            else if(sum>sal){
                return init(sal,left,mid-1);
            }
            else if(sum==sal){
                return mid;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your problem link redirects to http://codeforces.com and not to the actual problem. Does it require a login? Is this an active contest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before trying to improve the performance let's do a general review
of your code and clean it up a little.

#### Spacing

The code is not indented correctly. The use of (horizontal) whitespace
is inconsistent. I would suggest to leave at least spaces around
operators, keywords, and `{...}` blocks.

#### Variable names

Many variables names could be chosen better. For example:

> ```
> right = input.nextInt();
> ```

does not indicate that this is the total salary.

> ```
> public static int init(int sal, int left, int right)
> ```

does not tell anything about what the function does.
`int count` inside that function is not a count but a (running) sum.

#### Separate computation from I/O

Separating the actual computation from the I/O makes the main
method short, increases the clarity of the program, and allows you to add unit tests easily.

#### Use separate functions for self-contained tasks

The computation of the total salary from the current candidate
value in the binary search is done inside the search function.
Better move this to a separate function

```
private static int totalSalary(int initialSalary) {
    ...
}
```

because it is independent of the search algorithm. It also makes
the search function shorter and more self-explaining.

Also the initial call of the recursive search function is stuffed
into the main function:

> ```
> left =0;
> right = input.nextInt();
> sal = right;
> int presal = init(sal,left,right);
> ```

Again we can move this to a separate function:

```
private static int initialSalary(int totalSalary) {
    return binarySearch(totalSalary, 0, totalSalary);
}
```

#### The binary search function

- All code paths inside

  > ```
  >  while (left>=0 && left<=right){
  >      // ...
  >  }
  > ```

  *return* from the function, therefore an `if` would express that
  more clearly.
- I do not see why the `left>=0` is necessary.
- The medium index

  > ```
  > int mid = (left+right)/2;
  > ```

  and the corresponding salary is computed even if `right < left`, i.e.
  for an empty search interval.

I find it simpler to do a binary search in a *half-open* interval
\$ [\text{low}, \text{high}) \$

---

Summarizing the suggested changes so far, the program could look like
this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Salary {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int totalSalary = input.nextInt();
        int initialSalary = initialSalary(totalSalary);
        System.out.println(initialSalary);
    }

    private static int totalSalary(int initialSalary) {
        int salary = initialSalary;
        int sum = 0;
        while (salary > 0) {
            sum += salary;
            salary /= 10;
        }
        return sum;
    }

    private static int initialSalary(int totalSalary) {
        return binarySearch(totalSalary, 0, totalSalary + 1);
    }

    // Binary search original salary for given `totalSalary` in interval
    // `low` (included) ... `high` (excluded).
    private static int binarySearch(int totalSalary, int low, int high) {
        if (low >= high) {
            // Empty interval: not found
            return -1;
        } else {
            int mid = (low + high)/2;
            int total = totalSalary(mid);
            if (total == totalSalary) {
                // Found at `mid`
                return mid;
            } else if (total > totalSalary) {
                // Value at `mid` is too large, continue search in lower half.
                return binarySearch(totalSalary, low, mid);
            } else {
                // Value at `mid` is too small, continue search in upper half.
                return binarySearch(totalSalary, mid + 1, high);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That is not faster than your version, but (hopefully) better to 
understand, maintain and test.

(Another step towards more reusable code would be to define a binary search
which takes a function or lambda expression as parameter.)

#### Performance improvements

You do a binary search for the original salary, which is already quite
efficient. To make it even faster, the initial search interval can
be narrowed.

The initial salary \$ S \$ and the total salary \$ T \$ are related by
$$
T = S + \left\lfloor \frac{S}{10} \right\rfloor
 + \left\lfloor \frac{S}{100} \right\rfloor
+ \left\lfloor \frac{S}{1000} \right\rfloor + \ldots
$$

It follows that
$$
 T \le S +  \frac{S}{10} + \frac{S}{100} + \frac{S}{1000} + \ldots 
 = \frac{10 S}{9}
$$
and therefore
$$
 S \le \frac{9 T}{10} \, .
$$

For an estimate in the other direction we can use
$$
 T \ge S +  \frac{S}{10} - 1
$$
which implies
$$
 S \le \frac{10 (T+1)}{11} \, .
$$

As an example, for the input value \$ 3000 \$ this gives a search
interval \$ 2700 \ldots 2728 \$ instead of \$ 0 \ldots 3000 \$.

To use this improved bounds, only one function has to be updated:

```
    private static int initialSalary(int totalSalary) {
        int lowerBound = (totalSalary * 9)/10;
        int upperBound = ((totalSalary + 1)*10)/11;
        return binarySearch(totalSalary, lowerBound, upperBound + 1);
    }
```

#### Addendum: Integer ranges

For input values up to \$ 10^{18} \$ the Java `int` (which is
a signed 32-bit integer) is not large enough. You'll have to use
`long` instead.

Comment: So far the solution is perfect. Thank you so much. But the input is too big number 1<totalSalary<10^18.

Comment: @SheikhHanif: That was not apparent in your question originally. For  numbers in that range you have to replace all `int` by `long`

Comment: I replace all int variables with long. But how can I know is there are multiple x values which sum up y.

Comment: @SheikhHanif: If you found one solution then you could check the next smaller and larger value if it gives the same total salary. (But unless I am mistaken, that will *never* happen.)

Answer (score 0):

The most optimized solution is the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    int input = 0;
    int b;
    while ((b = System.in.read()) != -1) {
        if (b < 48 || b > 57)
            break;
        input = input * 10 + (b - 48);
    }
    int[] answer = new int[] {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, -1, 10, 11, ...};
    System.out.println(answer[input]);
}
```

It reads input argument directly from System.in without messing with Scanners, and computes the answer in a single lookup. The `answer` array can be easily precomputed.

Your solution is quite good in terms of performance, but since the input is in range [1..1018], the authors don't force people to try to be optimal.

Comment: I doubt that `Scanner.nextInt()` is a real performance problem if the input consists of a single line with a single number :)

Comment: @MartinR Me too :) But since the author wants the most optimized solution, removing an extra entity does the job.
And actually I've had a lot of troubles with Scanner when input contained a few hundred thousands of numbers.